# HTML5 and angularJS only conditional template solution possible (without ComponentOne pricetag)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am looking at the ComponentOne Wijmo angularJS conditional template example and dynamic columns with templates example further down the page here:

http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/CellTemplateIntro/CellTemplateIntro/

ComponentOne is asking quite a bit of $$$ for the software and I just need something built as a one-off.

I have a database of consignment customers and their inventory in MS Access from a form from about ten years ago.
I print out price labels, bar codes, product information, and several receipts for the each items on consignment using static html pages as templates.

I would like to have more control over what I am able to select to print out by moving to HTML5 and AngularJS.

Not to sound contemptuous, but looking at the ComponentOne example below, I am not clear on what is special or proprietary about what they have designed.  I would like to design my own version from scratch with guidance from the SO Brain Trust.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 conditional">
<wj-flex-grid 
    items-source="data3" 
    allow-sorting="false" 
    initialized="dynaColumnsFlexInit(s)"
    style="height:300px" 
    selection-mode="None"
    allow-dragging="None" 
    defer-resizing="true">
    <wj-flex-grid-column 
        header="Country" 
        binding="country">
        <wj-flex-grid-cell-template cell-type="GroupHeader">
            <ng-include 

    src="'scripts/CellTemplates/countryGroupHeaderTemplate.html'">
            </ng-include>
        </wj-flex-grid-cell-template>
    </wj-flex-grid-column>

    <!-- ng-init here creates the colCtx property with subproperties 
        that are isolated on a column level, that is not visible to 
        another columns but share data with all the cell templates
        defined for the column. -->
    <wj-flex-grid-column
        ng-repeat="col in statisticsColumns" 
        ng-init="colCtx = { reportType: col.reportType || 'Chart' }"
        ng-if="col.isAvailable"
        header="{​{col.header}}" 
        binding="{​{col.binding}}" 
        width="{​{col.width}}" 
        format="{​{col.format}}"
        aggregate="Sum" 
        align="{​{col.align}}">
        <wj-flex-grid-cell-template 
            cell-type="ColumnHeader" 
            ng-if="col.columnHeaderTemplateUrl">
            <ng-include src="col.columnHeaderTemplateUrl">
            </ng-include>
        </wj-flex-grid-cell-template>
        <wj-flex-grid-cell-template 
            cell-type="Group" 
            ng-if="col.groupTemplateUrl">
            <ng-include src="col.groupTemplateUrl">
            </ng-include>
        </wj-flex-grid-cell-template>
    </wj-flex-grid-column>

</wj-flex-grid>

<div style="margin:5px 0 5px"><b>Show statistics for:</b></div>
<wj-list-box 
    class="checkable-listbox"
    style="min-width:150px"
    items-source="statisticsColumns"
    display-member-path="header"
    checked-member-path="isAvailable">

</wj-list-box>
</div>
```

JS file

```
var getCv = function (data) {
var dataCv = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(data);
dataCv.sortDescriptions.push(new      
wijmo.collections.SortDescription('date', true));
dataCv.groupDescriptions.push(new 
wijmo.collections.PropertyGroupDescription('country'));
return dataCv;
}

$scope.data3 = getCv(data);

$scope.statisticsColumns = [
{
    binding: 'downloads',
    header: 'Downloads',
    width: '230',
    align: 'center',
    format: 'N0',
    columnHeaderTemplateUrl:   
'scripts/CellTemplates/statHeaderTemplate.html',
    groupTemplateUrl: 'scripts/CellTemplates/statGroupTemplate.html',
    reportType: 'Chart',
    isAvailable: true
},
{
    binding: 'sales',
    header: 'Sales',
    width: '230',
    align: 'center',
    format: 'N2',
    columnHeaderTemplateUrl: 
'scripts/CellTemplates/statHeaderTemplate.html',
    groupTemplateUrl: 'scripts/CellTemplates/statGroupTemplate.html',
    reportType: 'Chart',
    isAvailable: false
},
{
    binding: 'expenses',
    header: 'Expenses',
    width: '230',
    align: 'center',
    format: 'N2',
    columnHeaderTemplateUrl: 
'scripts/CellTemplates/statHeaderTemplate.html',
    groupTemplateUrl: 'scripts/CellTemplates/statGroupTemplate.html',
    reportType: 'Table',
    isAvailable: true
},
];

$scope.dynaColumnsFlexInit = function (flex) {
flex.collapseGroupsToLevel(0);
flex.columnHeaders.rows.defaultSize = 36;
flex.cells.rows.defaultSize = 156;
}
```

Am I missing something here behind the scenes, or would a generic flex grid of any kind accomplish the same thing without the hefty price $$$ ?

statHeaderTemplate file:

```
{​{$col.header}}:
<wj-combo-box 
items-source="['Chart', 'Table']" 
selected-value="colCtx.reportType"
style="width:100px;font-weight:400" 
is-editable="false">
</wj-combo-box>
```

statGroupTemplate file:

```
<div style="font-size:small;text-align:center">
<wj-flex-grid ng-if="colCtx.reportType == 'Table'"
    items-source="$item.items"
    is-read-only="false"
    headers-visibility="None"
    selection-mode="Cell"
    format="{​{$col.format}}"
    style="height:140px;width:200px">
<wj-flex-grid-column 
binding="date" 
width="*">
</wj-flex-grid-column>
<wj-flex-grid-column 
binding="{​{$col.binding}}" 
width="*">
</wj-flex-grid-column>
</wj-flex-grid>
<wj-flex-pie 
ng-if="colCtx.reportType == 'Chart'"
items-source="$item.items" 
binding="{​{$col.binding}}"
tooltip-content="<b>{value:{​{$col.format}}}</b><br/>{date:MMM yyyy}"                      
style="height:140px;width:140px;display:inline-block">
<wj-flex-chart-legend position="None"></wj-flex-chart-legend>
<wj-flex-pie-data-label 
content="'{date:MMM}'" 
position="Inside">
</wj-flex-pie-data-label>
</wj-flex-pie>
    </div>
```

countryGroupHeaderTemplate

```
<img ng-src="resources/{​{$item.name}}.png" />
{​{$item.name}}
```

If you notice the statHeaderTemplate, statGroupTemplate, and countryGroupHeaderTemplate have the Angular ng references, but I see the wijmo references interspersed (wj-whatever) and the wijmo collection (see the JS tab).

I am completely open to suggestions - - whatever works so I can make conditional selections for what I want to display within each column (and in what form I choose) for the corresponding row.

My goal is to keep the static html files for printing the borders and logos, and use the cell data from the flex chart as inputs to the templates so I can print out selected items in one pass.

I want to be realistic about whether this is something that can be dissected and redone using only HTML5 and AngularJS before I start the project. 
I want to get away from MS Access / VBA.

I am to the point that even if I have to give up the static HTML files templates to keep AngularJS happy, I am willing to do it, but the static HTML files have graphics, etc. I prefer to keep.

Is there a way to modify the templates which generate my static HTML files to work directly with AngularJS somehow instead? 
   Thanks in advance...

Comment: Im having a lot of trouble identifying the main question you're raising here.. Are you asking to represent an MSAccess DB inside angularJS ? Are you looking to clone wijimo ? And have you got any of your own code or attempt to show ?

Comment: I want to get completely away from a MS Access solution.  If I can use HTML5 and AngularJS only, that would be wonderful, but I do not want to get my hopes up.  I had not considered it as a possibility until I came across the ComponentOne demo.  Would I be trying to recreate the wheel here? Is this something realistically doable without them?

Comment: Its certainly possible to get away from MSAccess, and highly reccomended, but you will need some form of database / data storage, that could be anything from a text file somwhere to a SQL database somwhere to store the information. Angular and HTML are only client side tools..

Comment: You asked whether there is a way to manipulate your static html files directly.  Yes, you can use several javascript libraries for programmatic template creation; however, you will need to reference your local filesystem and browser security settings for writing files to disk.  If you are looking to get away from MS Access, I recommend using C# to keep things simple and flexible (and everything appears to be headed that way).  For a database, SQL server 2008 or later will work.